# Log file is created automatically by springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, loggerfactory

I wanted to use 2 log file for my springboot project.So, I created a logback.xml which is suitable for that purpose.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?> <configuration>

<timestamp key="timestamp" datePattern="ddMMyyyy"/>

    <appender name="STDOUT"
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                    <Pattern>
                            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
                    </Pattern>
            </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE"
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>logs/student${timestamp}.log</file>
            <encoder
                    class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
                    <Pattern>
                            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
                    </Pattern>
            </encoder>

            <rollingPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                    <!-- rollover daily -->
                    <fileNamePattern>logs/student_.%d{ddMMyyyy}.log
                    </fileNamePattern>
            </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE-AUDIT"
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>logs/teacher${timestamp}.log</file>
            <encoder
                    class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
                    <Pattern>
                            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss};%msg%n
                    </Pattern>
            </encoder>

            <rollingPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                    <!-- rollover daily -->
                    <fileNamePattern>logs/teacher_.%d{ddMMyyyy}.log
                    </fileNamePattern>
            </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.training.application" level="info"
            additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="audit-log" level="info" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

    <root level="error">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
```

My logger variables are like that :

```
private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TrainingBatch.class);//studentlog

private static Logger audit = LoggerFactory.getLogger("audit-log");//teacher log
```

My spring-boot applicatons runs with one argument.First one is `bootstrap.sh start student` or `./bootstrap.sh start teacher`

My problem is when I give the command `bootstrap.sh start student` application log info is written
student_... log file and also LOG.info etc.That is okey.It is correct.But another log file (student_...) is also created automatically.Or vica -versa.

How do we stop this situation?I want that If I give student command in command line,I want student log file should be created or If I give teachercommand in command line, teacher log file should be created.Server log info is not important for me.I wish they should not been written to any log file.

My bootstrap.sh =>

```
#!/bin/bash

######### PARAMs ######################################

APP_NAME="school"
JAR_NAME="school-1.0.1.jar"
#LOG_FILE="APP_NAME="school".log"
MAIN_APP_PATH="/main/microservices/training/batch/school"
JAVA_PATH="/home/main/java/jdk-13.0.2/bin/java"

############### APPLICATION MANAGEMENT PROPERTIES ###################

JARFILE="${MAIN_APP_PATH}/app/${JAR_NAME}"
#LOG="${MAIN_APP_PATH}/logs/${LOG_FILE}"
JAVA_OPT="- 


 Dspring.config.location 
 =file:${MAIN_APP_PATH}/config/application.properties"

 BOOT_MAIN_LOADER="org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher"
 PID_FILE=pid.file
 HOST=localhost
 PORT_FILE=port.file
 RUNNING=N
 SECRET_KEY=$2

 ############ DO NOT MODIFY ########

  if [ -f $PID_FILE ]; then
       PID=`cat $PID_FILE`
       if [ ! -z "$PID" ] && kill -0 $PID 2>/dev/null; then
              RUNNING=Y
       else
              rm -f $PID_FILE
      fi
  fi

   start()
 {
       if [ $RUNNING == "Y" ]; then
              echo "Application already started"
       else
               if [ ! -f "$JARFILE" ]; then
                      echo "ERROR: jar file not found."
                      echo "Please check the file location: ${JARFILE}"
              else
                      nohup $JAVA_PATH -jar $JAVA_OPT $JARFILE $SECRET_KEY &
                      echo $! > $PID_FILE
                      echo "Application $APP_NAME starting..."
                      sleep 1
                      #tail -0f $LOG
              fi
       fi
  }
```

Comment: can you open bootstrap.sh in ide and paste the file content?

Comment: Okey.I will update my question with bootstrap.sh

Comment: Can you check if my answer is working? I have edited my answer with bootsrtap.sh changes

Comment: I run ./bootstrap.sh start student but I got this error 'ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@30:19 - RuntimeException in Action for tag [appender] java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 6
logs/{sys:role}_.\d{2}\d{2}\d{4}.log
'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two file appenders use one file appender with a variable `role`. example

```
<appender name="FILE"
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>logs/{sys:role}${timestamp}.log</file>
            <encoder
                    class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
                    <Pattern>
                            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
                    </Pattern>
            </encoder>
            <rollingPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                    <!-- rollover daily -->
                    <fileNamePattern>logs/{sys:role}_.%d{ddMMyyyy}.log
                    </fileNamePattern>
            </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
```

change `bootstrap.sh` line

```
 nohup $JAVA_PATH -jar $JAVA_OPT $JARFILE $SECRET_KEY &
```

to

```
 nohup $JAVA_PATH -Drole="$2" -jar $JAVA_OPT $JARFILE $SECRET_KEY &
```